# Add Wordpress Iframe of 3rd party company which provide me search, and search results page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search, iframe

Yes, I know something like this has been asked over here before and I have searched but the one that is closest to what I'm trying to achieve doesn't have an answer anywhere.

So what I need is really simple.

I have a WordPress site and I want to integrate Iframe of 3rd party company which provide me search, and search results page.

I need some help with put the search on section and the search results on hidden field or somthing until we have some results to show.

I have got 2 pages from 3rd party company as follow:

Search.html

```
<pre>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="http://www.3rd_party_url/Default.aspx?urlresult=http://www.3rd_party_url/result.html" scrolling="no" width="350px" height="280px"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
</pre>
```

Result.html

```
<pre>

<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetQuery() {
            var url = window.location.href;
            url = url.substring(url.indexOf("?"))

            iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            iframe.src = "http://www.3rd_party_url/pleasewait.aspx" + url;

        }
        window.onload = function () 
        {
            GetQuery();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="myIframe" width="100%" height="800px" src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Not sure how to move on from there. I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!